# Return -1 if a procedure fails due to any error

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase15

How can I get the procedure to return -1 in sybase whenever there is an error? I want it to throw -1 irrespetcive of the type of error

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you tried `return -1`?